# CountIf and xlCellTypeVisible producing 1004 error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to count the number of fields that contain the word "Change", but this is being performed on a filtered list, so I am using the SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) property to test whether they are part of the filtered list. The sample code is shown below:

```
aWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(22, 10).Formula = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Cells(3, 10), Cells(20, 10)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), "Change")
```

But I am receieving the following error:

```
Run-time error'1004': Unable to get the CountIf property of the WorksheetFunction class
```

The following code, using Sum, works as expected though, which I find very odd

```
aWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(22, 7).Formula = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(3, 7), Cells(20, 7)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Sub CountValue()
Dim rngValues as Range
Dim varCounter as Variant
Dim counter as Byte

Set rngvalues = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$J$3:$J$20")

For Each varCounter in rngvalues.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    If varCounter = "Change" Then
       counter = counter + 1
    End if
Next

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Range("$J$22").Value = counter

End Sub
```

Comment: That was my next approach, but does anyone know why the above approach doesn't work?

Comment: You shouldn't mix VBA functions inside WorksheetFunctions without evaluate